# Instagram personal integration with app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to integrate instagram into my app. However the instagram api page says that the api for personal usage is deprecated [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) and the facebook graph api they are linkning to says that it can only be used for businesses.

> The Instagram API Platform can be used to build non-automated, authentic, high-quality apps and services. Select the API permissions that you would like to integrate with your service or product so you can effectively utilize the Instagram API and help businesses achieve their objectives.
>
> The API permissions available on this page are currently only available for Instagram business accounts. These APIs do not support regular personal profiles; you can learn more about business profiles here. If you are interested in the consumer (non-business) use cases that involve the Instagram login, please refer to the developer site for the former API permissions.
>
> Check out some resources that may help you in development: Documentation and Instagram Platform Policies.

And below that it says

> **To help businesses view their own content within third party apps: Basic Permission**
>   This use case is meant for apps that allow business profiles to log in and access their own content; for example, an app that allows businesses to print their own pictures. Apps that fall into this use case must use the basic permission.
>
> **To help brands and advertisers understand, manage, and discover their audience: Comment Moderation and Insights Permissions**
>   This use case is meant for apps that allow businesses to access their account insights, moderate and reply to comments, and discover media of other business profiles.

As for the usecase that I need, I basically need what Tinder has. The ability for people to link their instagram accounts and link to their account for other people. It would be nice to be able to get the number of followers as well.

I can't really find anything how to integrate instagram for personal accounts, the information above is the only thing I've really found.

Currently users log in via facebook so if there is some easy way to integrate with that, that would be nice. But really any way at all to make it work that is not deprecated would be nice.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: @user3589771 no :(
Haven't really had time to do any super indepth research about it yet, but I'll look into it this coming week. Would be nice if someone knew how to do it though :/

Comment: @MathiArasan hi, I think I found the new API (I just randomly came across this question again and looked into it)

I posted an answer to my question, so if you for some reason still need it you should find it there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was looking through my old questions I came across this one. I did some more looking into it and think I found the "new" Instagram API. It's now seemingly part of the Facebook Graph API. The API is called the Instagram Basic Display API which would give me the required data (photos, names etc.).

The API can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api)